# Typecasting problems in powershell regarding -match and regular expression

Tags: regex, powershell, match, operator-keyword

I’m writing a function that collects the values hat follow a certain named parameter. The code is the following (for demonstration purposes this is only an excerpt without parsing parameters etc.)

```
$commandline=@("ddddd","-anotherswitch2","djfjdsfa","-recurse",1,2,3,"-anotherswitch","-recurse",5,6, "-anotherswitch","kslsdfgvl")

$searchswitch="-recurse"
$Paths=@()
$matches=0
$counter=0               

while ( ($Counter -lt $commandline.length-1) -AND ($matches -lt 1))                    
{

    if ($commandline[$counter] -eq $searchswitch)
    {
        $matches++
        $counter++

        # while argument does not start with "-" and we haven't reached the end of the array

        While( -NOT ($commandline[$counter] -match "^-") -AND ($counter -lt $commandline.length) ) 

        {
            $Paths+= $($commandline[$counter])
            $counter++

        }                 
    }
    else
    {
        $counter++
    }
}

$Paths
```

The code works almost as expected, but it throws the following error message.

```
Der Wert "System.Collections.Hashtable" vom Typ "System.Collections.Hashtable" kann nicht in den Typ "System.Int32" konvertiert werden.
Bei D:\Unbenannt5.ps1:18 Zeichen:67
+                         While( -NOT ($commandline[$counter] -match <<<<  "^-") -AND ($counter -lt $commandline.length) ) 
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

1
2
3
```

The error message is the German version of *Value "System.Collections.Hashtable" of type "System.Collections.Hashtable" cannot be converted to type "System.Int32"*.

I’ve narrowed down this to the 8th element of the commandline array (-anotherswitch). Can anybody help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was trying to get around the native Powershell parameter parsing to functions by giving this functionality you indicate to a §args based approach. If I use the native powershell approach with `param()` the whole function would be obsolete:-) However, I would be interested in knowing what causes the error. It might have to to with the hyphen-minus in the parameter name

Answer (score 4):

What you got is because `-match` operator returns all the matches in a variable called `$Matches` and it overwrites your variable of the same name. Like so,

```
PS C:\> "foo" -match "f[o]o"
True
PS C:\> $Matches

Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              foo
```

This is [documented](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) a feature:

> -Match 
>         Description: Matches a string using regular expressions. 
>                      When the input is scalar, it populates the
>                      $Matches automatic variable.

Solution: use another a name for the variable.

Answer (score 2):

If I am interpreting you correctly, this code is so that you can take an arbitrary number of extra parameters. If so, please allow me to make this easier for you:

```powershell
function My-Function {
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [Switch]
    $Recurse , # I'm guessing the arbitrary number of parameters comes after this

    [Parameter(
        ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true
    )]
    $Remaining
)
    $Remaining # This is an array of all the extra arguments
}
```

I realize this may not answer the exact question you had, but instead may be a way to sidestep the need for all that code.

If I have not captured exactly what you're trying to do, please explain or show the whole function.